# React, too much data on storage with AppSync (serverless app)

Tags: reactjs, local-storage, aws-appsync

I have a React that works with AppSync for a serverless app (AWS). Til now, everything goes well, the app doesn't usee too much data (i don't know how many data is in MB, but let's say that the bigger services brings like 2MB of data, a JSON of 550 rows). But now we are working with a service that brings almost 5000 rows, and we are getting this error:

[image]

The warning is in this method:

[image]

Is there a way to have more space on local storage? the app what is doing is saving all data in storage while there's no internet connection, so we need all the data that we are working on.

Answer (score 0):

Size of localstorage is about 10MB, you can't really extend it, for your problem I advice you to use [service workers](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/primers/service-workers) one of it's purposes is to make app accessible offline